# How do I connect LG P500 to Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: lg-optimus-one, macos

I've been given a nice LG-P500 phone for my 67th birthday.

How the heck do I transfer music, photos and videos from the phone to my iMac OS X Lion, and vice versa?

I can't access the mini-SD card, so I can't find the LG PC Suite IV which is referred to in the P500 "Simple Manual".  In the "Important notice" pink pages bit, in section 9 I can get up to the first part of para. 4: I can turn on USB storage on the phone.  The phone opens "Image Capture" when I connect it by USB to the iMac.  There is nothing visible.  And of course an .exe file is for Microsoft Windows, not Apple.

Don't tell me I have to buy Parallels.  And if the only way is sending stuff up into the clouds and retrieving it again, I'm not impressed. LG should surely have a way of doing it direct to Mac.  After all, Mac OS isn't exactly new!

So, two requests:

- Where can I download a Mac Lion version of LG PC Suite?
- Where can I download a "Full Manual"?  The "Simple Manual" - which you can download from all over the place - says "you can do stuff" but not, unfortunately, "this is how you do stuff."  Not much use.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download and install **Android File Transfer** software. It will solve all the problems.

Once connected the device, turn on the file transfer mode from your mobile device and you are good to go!